# Delete rows from a matrix based on several thresholds in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, filter, delete-row

Matlab: I have a matrix with two columns and a large number of rows. I would like to keep only rows where the entry in the first column is smaller than a threshold 1 and the entry of column 2 ist smaller than another threshold 2. In the end I would like to have a matrix with still two columns but less rows. 
I tried something like:

```
CorrLPX(CorrLPX(:,1) < -0.2 & CorrLPX(:,2) < -0.3) = [];
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

To keep the original number of columns, you should use logical indexing only on the rows and select all columns. This can be done by the colon operator:

```
CorrLPX((CorrLPX(:,1) < -0.2 & CorrLPX(:,2) < -0.3),:) = [];
```